# Undefined Method for Ruby Module

Tags: ruby, input, methods, module

I'm new to Ruby and programming in general and I'm working on a few practice projects. I have a module for my game that checks to see if my virtual pet is hungry.

```
module Reaction
  
  def hungry?
    if @dragon.hunger > 1
      @dragon.hunger -= 1
      print 'Mmmmmmm, thanks for the people parts!'
    else
      print 'I\'m full already!'
    end
  end
```

Then on my game file I have a class called StartGame.

```
require_relative 'dragon'
require_relative 'reaction'

class StartGame
  include Reaction
  attr_reader :dragon
```

I'm then attempting to use the module within my user_input method to check if the pet is already hungry.

```
 def user_input
    print "How would you like to interact with your dragon?\n"
    print "Feed, Sleep, Play, Pet, or Quit\n"
    print "Input:\n"
    @user_input = gets.capitalize.chomp
 if @user_input == 'Feed'
   Reaction.hungry?
 end
```

I seem to continuously get this error "undefined method `hungry?' for Reaction:Module (NoMethodError)"

The code within the module works perfectly when used like this

```
if @user_input == 'Feed'
    if @dragon.hunger > 1
      @dragon.hunger -= 1
      print 'Mmmmmmm, thanks for the people parts!'
    else
      print 'I\'m full already!'
    end
  end
```

I'm just not certain what I'm doing wrong here to search google effectively how to get the method to be defined.

Comment: Can you confirm this is not really Rails related (or included in the context of a Rails app) and that class `StartGame` is not inheriting ApplicationRecord ? What is flagging is that you use `hungry?` As a class method. Then in your module you probably need to declare `hungry?` as `self.hungry?`

Comment: @Maxence My apologies. This was not supposed to be a rails question. Not sure how the tag got added but I have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

You module really haven't this method because `hungry?` is instance method

You include it to `StartGame`, so you can call it on this class instance

```
start_game.hungry?
```

But it looks that it is not game method, but dragon's (for example you have other hungry monsters)

So you need rewrite method and include this module to dragon class and call it as `@dragon.hungry?`

Methods with question marks usually are used to return boolean (`true` or `false`)

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the heads up about using question marks in methods. I was able to include the module but was calling Reaction.hungry?  Changed the method to 'feed_response' and called it in the class by removing 'Reaction.' before 'feed_response'